# JOIN MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql

I have following tables format:

**members**

```
 mem_id | mem_name
    ------------------
     1         A
     2         B 
     3         C
```

**project_members**

```
fk_mem_id | meb_parent_id
-------------------------
    1          0
    2          1
    3          2
```

and I require result like:

```
mem_id | child| parent
--------------------------
   1      A     NULL
   2      B      A
   3      C      B
```

I tried but fail.. any idea....?

```
SELECT pm.*, m1.meb_name as child, m2.meb_name as parent 
FROM members m1
LEFT JOIN members m2 
ON m1.meb_parent_id = m2.meb_id
```

Comment: @Crontab - I looked at your nickname, and the first thing that came to mind was - about time that that was said! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT project_members.fk_mem_id, 
       a.mem_name AS child, 
       b.mem_name AS parent 
FROM   project_members 
       INNER JOIN members a 
               ON project_members.fk_mem_id = a.mem_id 
       LEFT JOIN members b 
              ON project_members.meb_parent_id = b.mem_id
```